# Socket Java to C++ - Messages are always 8192 characters long

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp, winsock

I am implementing a TCP socket connection from a java to a C++ programm. Currently it's one way but should become two-way someday. My messages are pretty long (~100.000 characters). Somehow my application only sends 8192 characters/bytes at once. How can that be? Is there any tool that can help debugging? Both, client and server, run on a local windows machine. I am not familar with network programming, so any help is appreciated! Thanks alot in advance!

Here is my code so far:

**JAVA:**
*make a connection:*

```
try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketPort);
            System.out.println("waiting for client ...");
            while (true) {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("client connected.");
                if (clientSocket!=null) break;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
        }
```

*send stuff:*

```
OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

//send the new data to client
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out, true);
String outString = "VERY LONG TEXT ENDING WITH SPECIAL LETTER LIKE $";
pw.println(outString);
```

**C++:**

*make a connection*

```
bool connectToHost(int PortNo, char* IPAddress)
{
    //Start up Winsock…
    WSADATA wsadata;

    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);

    //Did something happen?
    if (error)
        return false;

    //Did we get the right Winsock version?
    if (wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
        return false;
    }

    //Fill out the information needed to initialize a socket…
    SOCKADDR_IN target; //Socket address information

    target.sin_family = AF_INET; // address family Internet
    target.sin_port = htons (PortNo); //Port to connect on
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (IPAddress); //Target IP

    mSocket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket
    if (mSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't create the socket
    }  

    //Try connecting...
    if (connect(mSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't connect
    }
    else
        return true; //Success
}
```

*receive stuff:*

```
if (connectToHost(3141, "127.0.0.1")) 
    {
        int iResult;
        char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN]; // DEFAULT_BUFLEN = 1000000
        // Receive until the peer closes the connection
        do {

            iResult = recv(mSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0); // DEFAULT_BUFLEN = 1000000
            if ( iResult > 0 )
            {                 
                std::cout<<"recvbuf: "<< recvbuf[strlen(recvbuf)-1]<<""<< std::endl;  //not the last character that I sent, but supposed to be
                std::cout<<"recvbuf size: "<< iResult <<""<< std::endl; //fist are 8192 and then add up until sent size 
            }
            else if ( iResult == 0 )
                printf("Connection closed\n");
            else
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

        } while( iResult > 0 );
    } else 
    {
        printf("connect failed\n");
    }
```

Comment: IS 8192  bytes received repeatedly every time?

Comment: yes, even if the sent string is smaller.

Comment: First, Strlen() returns the length of a c-style string which is ended with a null terminator, so likely you have null in the buffer. Second return value of recv is the length of the message if it's successful. You shouldn't need to use strlen.

Comment: thanks @TonyJ. I edited the code. The values in iResult now sum up to the size that I sent. Is there a way that it won't be received in chunks? I made a small client in java and there the full size is received at once, so I assume that the error is on the c++ side.

Comment: @Anthea You could try `MSG_WAITALL` as the flag value in the call to `recv`.  Also, your output statement should be: `recvbuf[iResult - 1]`, and not the usage of `strlen`.

Comment: `recv()` does not guarantee receiving the full size of the buffer uninterruptedly. If after it returns the count is below the expected value, move the buffer pointer and call the function again with the remainder length. Then, when all the bytes are received, exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

TCP sockets work on a byte stream concept. The TCP socket ensures your data arrives without error and in order as a byte stream. The sender adds bytes to the TCP byte stream, and the socket takes care of sending them to the destination. The socket does not separate your logical messages; it is your responsibility to insert separators for any logical messages that are embedded in the byte stream. The TCP socket does not necessarily send a packet on the socket every time you write bytes to the socket. This is to increase the efficiency, as measured by the number of data bytes versus the total bytes sent (data + overhead). You can read about [Nagle's algorithm for TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).

When reading from a socket, you are again consuming the byte stream. The number of times you need to call receive may not match the number of times send was called. But you know the correct bytes will be delivered in order, and the number of these bytes will be the same as those sent.

The size 8192 is probably the buffer size that triggers sending a packet.

If you send only 1 byte, then flush the socket, you should see only the one byte on the receiving end. You can also disable Nagle's algorithm by setting `TCP_NODELAY` in the [java socket options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't receive more at a time than was in the socket receive buffer. Raise the socket receive buffer size from 8192, with `setsockopt()`, and do the same at the sending end for the socket send buffer.

Comment: I tried int iOptVal = 20; setsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *) &iOptVal, sizeof(int)); directly after declaring the socket, but it has no effect.